# why are the files under "/root" directory showed on desktop in centos after I deleted "/root/Desktop" folder

Tags: linux, centos

I deleted the folder `Desktop/` under `/root` directory, and when I restart my centos, I found all the files under `~` (`/root`, I logged on as root) are showed on desktop, why this happened? how can I fix this? thanks.

Comment: First of all, why are you running as root? That's just ... dangerous. Also, what desktop manager and file manager are you using?

Comment: @cyphar, I am using the default file manager of centos 6.4: Nautilus 2.28.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the `~/Desktop` folder again, your desktop should revert to that.

Comment: Yes, I came up with this idea too, and I did, but the files are still show on desktop, I open the "root's Home" folder on desktop in file manager, I can see all the files, which are under "~"(/root) directory, even the "/root/Desktop". I use "ls -i" command in terminal to list files under /root, I can see all the files have 2 hard links, but when I use "find -inum" to search specific inode number, I just find one file.

Comment: @DavidSmith "root's Home", which is typically `/root`, is not the same thing as `/root/Desktop`. I suspect that, if you open "root's Home", it'll show the same stuff regardless of whether `/root/Desktop` exists or not (except for `/root/Desktop`, at least...).

Comment: @DavidSmith "Root's Home" is the root home directory (aka `/root`).

Comment: ***PROBLEM SOLVED!*** the Desktop base dir is configured in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, I just added back `Desktop` directory under `~` and set `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"` in the config file